# AngularJS: Keeping a promise around to guarantee something has loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS needs to load a mapping (from my API) that is needed by the rest of the application to continue to make API calls. My current solution is saving the Promise that is used to load the map and having making every future API call using promise.then(...). Is this the right solution? Is it ok to keep a promise around and repeatedly call .then() on it?

Comment: Why not use `run` if the whole app depends on it?

Comment: You should be making a service and polling it, every x seconds or on user's demand. Wrap your promise around your API request.

Comment: Yes, this is the good solution. A promise is just a wrapper for the data; `promise.then()` has no performance impact, if this is what you worry about.

Answer (score 0):

As @blackhole noted, Promise.then() on an already-resolved promise is fast. It's not zero work, but it's just a quick check.

But if this data is a pre-requisite for your application, it seems a terrible burden in CODE to have to check it every time an API call needs to be made. What if you add a second pre-requisite? It's really messy to have to check this every single time in the future.

Both ngRoute and uiRouter allow you to require a resolved promise before starting a controller. They're great patterns for this in an Angular app because you can be granular - you can have a lot of smaller pre-requisites through the app that need to be resolved before those views start.

Here's a sample for ngRoute:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      resolve: {
        init: ['MyService', function(MyService {
          return MyService.getMyData();
        }]
      }
    });
}]);
```

and here's one for uiRouter:

```
getMyData.$inject = ['MyService'];
function getMyData(MyService) {
    return MyService.getMyData();
}

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '^/',
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    resolve: {
        myData: getMyData
    }
});
```

Since most apps want some form of routing anyway, it's an easy pattern to let the router do this for you, but as @Dave Newton pointed out, you could also do this with .run() if you want to roll-your-own.

If you cannot or do not want to use one of the routing mechanisms, you can also manually trigger Angular's bootstrap after loading the asset. Documentation for this is provided here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

But basically you're doing this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Then you remove the ng-app directive from your top-level DOM element, wherever you put it.

Comment: If all my routes also depend on this initialization,  would I have to include `resolve` in all the routes manually?

Comment: You would... but if EVERY route requires the asset, why don't you just include it as a <HEAD> block <SCRIPT> element of some kind or embed it into the page? As a third option you can bootstrap manually. I updated my answer with that option.